# Finding if the next element is smaller than the one before it and deleting it from the list python

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my code, I am writing a method that will check if the next element is smaller than the previous element and if it is, it will delete it.

Example:

Input: `[1, 20, 10, 30]`

Desired output:  `[1,20,30]`

Actual output: `[30]`

```
def findSmaller(s):
    i = -1
    y = []
    while i <= len(s):
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if s[i+1] <= s[i]:
                del s[i + 1]
                y.append(s[i])
            i += 1
            return y
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Don't you want the return statement to be indented only one level?

Comment: don't iterate & change your list. It's wrong.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @BlueMonday Lists are mutable in python so `s` changes after the method is run.

Comment: Removing items from a list you're iterating over can lead to unexpected results. See [Removing items from a list while iterating over the list](http://sopython.com/canon/95/removing-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-the-list/) for details. A rough analogy: it's like sawing off a tree branch that you're sitting on. If you're not careful where you saw, Bad Things _will_ happen. :)

Comment: You say "check if the next element is smaller than the previous element and if it is, it will delete it", but your code uses `<=`.  Say you had `[10, 20, 20, 30]` as input -- do you want `[10, 20, 30]` as output or `[10,20,20,30]`?

Comment: What if two items are smaller than the previous one, for example `[30, 20, 25]`, do you want that to be `[30]` or `[30, 25]`?

Comment: Yes, I was just gonna say that, I want to do this, well if my list is [5, 20, 10, 15, 30] I want to output [5,20,30]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
def findSmaller(s):
    # sets p (previous) as the first value in s
    p = s[0]
    # initializes y to be an array and sets the first value to p
    y = [p]
    # iterates over s, starting with the second element
    for i in s[1::]:
        # checks if i is greater than or equal to the previous element
        if i >= p:
            # if it is, i is appended to the list y
            y.append(i)
            # also set the previous value to i, so the next iteration can check against p
            p = i
    #returns the list
    return y
```

What this does is iterate over `s` and checks if the current item in the list is greater than or equal to the previous element in the list. If it is then it appends it to `y`, and `y` is returned.

Try out the code [here](https://repl.it/EPdz).

Comment: Can you tell me what does y = [p] means?

Comment: This creates a list `y` where `p` is first element in the list.

Comment: @BlueMonday I commented every line in the code to explain it.

Comment: @BlueMonday I just changed it so it does that.

Comment: Try it out now. I provided a link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncertain about how your loops work **I recommend adding in some print statements**. That way you can see what your loop is actually doing, especially in more complicated problems this is useful.

Something like this would solve your problem.

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4]
for k in range(0,len(a)-2): #-2 so that one don't go past the loops length
    #print(k)
    y = a
    if(a[k]>a[k+1]):
        del y[k+1] #delete the k+1 element if it is
```

Comment: Wouldn't I get an index out of range error on this one?
edit: ops I guess not, I see now, thanks for the info, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether you need to do some calculation later with the list you can use a generator

```
s = [1, 20, 10, 30]

def find_smaller_generator(l: list):
    last_item = None
    for item in l:
        if last_item is None or item >= last_item: 
            last_item = item
            yield item
def find_smaller_list(l: list):
    return list(find_smaller_generator(l))



print(find_smaller_list(s))

for i in find_smaller_generator(s):
    print(i)

print([i**2 for i in find_smaller_generator(s)])
```

this returns:

```
[1, 20, 30]

1
20
30

[1, 400, 900]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s =  [5, 20, 10, 15, 30]
>>> max_so_far = s[0]
>>> result = []
>>> for x in s:
        if x >= max_so_far:
            result.append(x)
            max_so_far = x

>>> result
[5, 20, 30]
```

Comment: This is, at the very least, light on explanation.

Comment: There is only one interesting variable and I believe that it is well named.