# Python library pdfplumber does not extract lines

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to use pdfplumber to extract text line by line from a pdf document.

I can open a page from the pdf document and view the text on a page basis

```
pdf = pdfplumber.open(data_drive_os+dataloc+'/'+ file + '.pdf')

page = pdf.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```

This results in the following text:

```
Anti-Money Laundering and 
Counter-Terrorism Financing Act 2006 
No. 169, 2006 
Compilation No. 48 
Compilation date:      20 December 2018 
Includes amendments up to:  Act No. 156, 2018 
Registered:        7 January 2019 
 
Prepared by the Office of Parliamentary Counsel, Canberra 
Authorised Version C2019C00011 registered 07/01/2019
```

So I know that the text is there. However, when I try to extract the text line by line, it returns an empty list:

```
print(page.lines)
```

Returns:

```
[]
```

I can also extract the characters:

```
print(page.chars)
```

Returns:

```
[{'fontname': 'ABCDEE+Times New Roman', 'adv': Decimal('2.010'), 'upright': 1, 'x0': Decimal('120.500'), 'y0': Decimal('797.823'), 'x1': Decimal('122.510'), 'y1': Decimal('805.863'), 'width': Decimal('2.010'), 'height': Decimal('8.040'), 'size': Decimal('8.040'), 'object_type': 'char', 'page_number': 1, 'stroking_color': 0, 'non_stroking_color': 0, 'text': ' ', 'top': Decimal('36.057'), 'bottom': Decimal('44.097'), 'doctop': Decimal('36.057')}, {'fontname': 'ABCDEE+Times New Roman', 'adv': Decimal('6.138'), 'upright': 1, 'x0': Decimal('120.500'), 'y0': Decimal('170.315'), 'x1': Decimal('126.638'), 'y1': Decimal('181.355'), 'width': Decimal('6.138'), 'height': Decimal('11.040'), 'size': Decimal('11.040'), 'object_type': 'char', 'page_number': 1, 'stroking_color': 0, 'non_stroking_color': 0, 'text': 'P', 'top': Decimal('660.565'), 'bottom': Decimal('671.605'), 'doctop': Decimal('660.565')}, {'fontname': 'ABCDEE+Times New Roman', 'adv': Decimal('3.676'), 'upright': 1, 'x0': Decimal('126.638'), 'y0': Decimal('170.315'), 'x1': Decimal('130.315'), 'y1': Decimal('181.355'), 'width': Decimal('3.676'), 'height': Decimal('11.040'), 'size': Decimal('11.040'), 'object_type': 'char', 'page_number': 1, 'stroking_color': 0, 'non_stroking_color': 0, 'text': 'r', 'top': Decimal('660.565'), 'bottom': Decimal('671.605'), 'doctop': Decimal('660.565')}, {'fontname': 'ABCDEE+Times New Roman', 'adv': Decimal('4.902'), 'upright': 1, 'x0': Decimal('130.315'), 'y0': Decimal('170.315'), 'x1': Decimal('135.216'), 'y1': Decimal('181.355'), 'width': Decimal('4.902'), 'height': Decimal
```

etc. So there is definitely text there.

From reading the documentation page [here](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#objects), I should be able to use .lines to produce the lines, but it does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is in the documentation you post:

> .lines, each representing a single 1-dimensional line.

This refers to geometric lines (vector elements), not lines of text. PDF doesn't have a concept of lines of text (or any higher order collection of characters).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract text lines you need to use PDFMiner (which works underneath pdfplumber anyway). It groups characters on each page into text lines and text lines into text boxes, accounting for horizontal\vertical alignment. https://pdfminer-docs.readthedocs.io/programming.html

You can get access to PDFMiner layout objects from pdfplumber page:

```
# need to pass in laparams, otherwise pdfplumber page would not
# have high level pdfminer layout objects, only LTChars. 
pdf = pdfplumber.open(r'document.pdf', laparams={})
page = pdf.pages[0].layout
for element in page:
    if isinstance(element, LTTextLineHorizontal):
        print(element.get_text())
    if isinstance(element, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
        for line in element:
            print(line.get_text())
```

Or you can use PDFMiner directly:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages

path = r'document.pdf'
for page in extract_pages(path):
    for element in page:
        if isinstance(element, LTTextLineHorizontal):
            print(element.get_text())
        if isinstance(element, LTTextBoxHorizontal):
            for line in element:
                print(line.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detection for lines of text, the best way to do so is probably to loop through each of the pdf object's characters, checking char metadata for changes. pdfplumber offers a lot of metadata, but the most useful for you here will probably be:

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| y0 | Distance of bottom of character from bottom of page. |
| y1 | Distance of top of character from bottom of page. |
| top | Distance of top of character from top of page. |
| bottom | Distance of bottom of the character from top of page. |

from the [documentation](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#char-properties).

With this, you can add newline checks by seeing if character 1 has a different distance than character 2 from, for instance, the top of the page. You can add each character and its `top` value to a list like such:

```
your_pdf = pdfplumber.open(your\path\here)
pg28=your_pdf.pages[27]
your_page = pg28.extract_text()
char_list = []
for each_char in pg28.chars:
     char_list.append([each_char["text"], each_char["top"]])
```

Then you can compare each top value to the next one in the list, as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439487/finding-if-the-next-element-is-smaller-than-the-one-before-it-and-deleting-it-fr). This should help you figure out which characters are on a newline or on the same line.